# Can I install Windows from a DVD-ROM?

Tags: windows-7

As I understand it, ROM can only read data and not write (at least to a disc). For example, I'm not able to burn anything unfortunately. But if I put in a Windows installation disc, would it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I understand it, ROM can only read data and not write (at least to a disc). For example, I'm not able to burn anything unfortunately. But if I put in a Windows installation disc, would it work?

Yes. Many Windows versions were literally *sold* on CD-ROM and later DVD-ROM discs. (That's actually where the Windows "ISO"s come from – they're images of the ISO-9660 data that would be found on a CD.)

I still have a CD of Windows 98 and a DVD of Windows 7.

In general, the Windows installer does not require being able to write anything to the install media; it's like a Linux "live CD" that runs entirely from a RAM-disk.